# Solve analytically an equation with a definite integral

Tags: probability-distributions, definite-integrals, integral-equations

Given a probability distribution $p(u)$, I need to solve the following system where $\gamma,\; \alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ are the unknowns:
\begin{align}
1=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} p(u) \frac{-1}{\gamma-(u-x+\alpha \tau)^{2}}\mathrm{d}u
\end{align}
\begin{align}
\alpha=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} p(u) \frac{(u-x+\alpha \tau)}{\gamma-(u-x+\alpha \tau)^{2}}
\end{align}

I am only interested in an expression for $\alpha$, and I have been solving this system numerically.

**Is there a way to simplify these equations for a general** $p(u)$ **?**

If not, if we choose $p(u)$ to be a simple distribution (bimodal, uniform for example), is is then possible to simplify these equations without using numerical methods ?

($x$ is a real number, and $\tau$ is a parameter such that $-1<\tau<1$ and $\tau \neq 0$).

Any remark, advice or reference to a book is always appreciated, thank you very much.

Edit :

The original equation has a dependency on an extra term $y\in\mathbb{R}$ :

\begin{align}
1=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} p(u) \frac{-1}{\gamma-(u-x+\alpha \tau)^{2}-\frac{y^2}{\left(\tau-1\right)^{2}}}\mathrm{d}u
\end{align}
\begin{align}
\alpha=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} p(u) \frac{(u-x+\alpha \tau)}{\gamma-(u-x+\alpha \tau)^{2}-\frac{y^2}{\left(\tau-1\right)^{2}}}
\end{align}
I noticed that for any distribution $p(u)$ my solution is independent of $y$ (I don't know why) so I thought that setting $y=0$ would make things easier.

Comment: How do you handle the singularity when the denominator vanishes?

Comment: I edited the question. There is an extra term in the original equation, so the denominator should never vanish I think.

Comment: The denominator still vanishes, so presumably you're calculating a principle value integral.

Comment: I am not sure I understand, could you explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us consider the given integral equations in the form of

$$\left\{\begin{align}
&1 = \int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty \dfrac{1}{(u-a)^2 - b^2}\,p(u)\text{ d}u\\
&\alpha = \int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty \dfrac{a-u}{(u-a)^2-b^2}\,p(u)\text{ d}u,
\end{align}\right.\tag1$$
where
$$a=x-\alpha\tau,\quad b^2 = \gamma-\dfrac {y^2}{(r-1)^2}.\tag2$$

Then
$$\left\{\begin{align}
&b+\alpha = \int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty \dfrac{b+a-u}{(u-a)^2 - b^2}\,p(u)\text{ d}u
 = \int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty p(u)\dfrac{\text{ d}u}{a-u-b}\\
&b-\alpha = \int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty \dfrac{b+u-a}{(u-a)^2-b^2}\,p(u)\text{ d}u
 = \int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty p(u)\dfrac{\text{ d}u}{u-a-b},
\end{align}\right.\tag3$$

Obtained integrals allow more rich choice of the further steps. Detalization of the function $p(u)$ looks nesessary.

$\color{green}{\mathbf{Case\ p(u) = \frac12\delta(u+1)-\frac12\delta(u-1)}}.$

**Via (1).**

Formulas $(1)$ give the system

$$\left\{\begin{align}
&1 = \frac12\dfrac1{(u-a)^2 - b^2}\bigg|_{-1}^1 = \frac12\dfrac1{(a-1)^2 - b^2}-\frac12\dfrac1{(a+1)^2 - b^2}\\
&\alpha = \frac12\dfrac{a-u}{(u-a)^2-b^2}\bigg|_{-1}^1 = \frac12\dfrac{a-1}{(a-1)^2-b^2}-\frac12\dfrac{a+1}{(a+1)^2-b^2},
\end{align}\right.$$

$$
\begin{cases}
v=u-2\\[4pt]
(a-1)u-(a+1)v = 2\alpha\\
u = \dfrac1{(a-1)^2 - b^2}\\
v = \dfrac{a+1}{(a+1)^2-b^2}
\end{cases}\Rightarrow
\begin{cases}
u = a-\alpha+1\\[4pt]
v = a-\alpha-1\\
a-\alpha+1 = \dfrac1{(a-1)^2 - b^2}\\
a-\alpha-1 = \dfrac{1}{(a+1)^2-b^2},
\end{cases}
$$
\begin{cases}
(a-1)^2 - b^2 = \dfrac1{a-\alpha+1}\\
(a+1)^2 - b^2 = \dfrac1{a-\alpha -1},
\end{cases}

$$2a(a-\alpha)^2-2a-1 = 0,\tag4$$
i.e. $\alpha$ does not depend of $b.$

Let
$$p=\dfrac\tau{\tau+1},\quad q=\dfrac x{\tau+1},\quad z= a-\alpha = x-(\tau+1)\alpha,\tag5$$
then
$$a=z+\alpha = z + \frac{x-z}{\tau+1} = \dfrac x{\tau+1}+ \dfrac\tau{\tau+1}z
= p z + q,$$
$$\alpha = a-z = (p-1)$$
and from $(4)$ should
$$2(pz+q)(z^2-1)-1=0,$$
with the [solution](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2%28q-pz%29%28z%5E2-1%29+-1+%3D+0)
$$z = \frac1{6p}\left(r - \frac{12 p^2 + 4 q^2}r + 2 q\right),\tag5$$
where
$$r = \sqrt[3]{\sqrt{(-72 p^2 q - 54 p^2 + 8 q^3)^2 - (12 p^2 + 4 q^2)^3} - 72 p^2 q - 54 p^2 + 8 q^3}.\tag6$$

Note that $(5)$ gives correct solution even if $p$ is complex.

**Via (3).**

Formulas $(3)$ give the system

$$\left\{\begin{align}
&b+\alpha = \frac12\dfrac1{a-u-b}\bigg|_{-1}^1 = \frac12\dfrac1{a-1-b}-\frac12\dfrac1{a+1-b} = \dfrac 1{(a-b)^2-1}\\
&b-\alpha = \frac12\dfrac1{u-a-b}\bigg|_{-1}^1 = \frac12\dfrac1{1-a-b}+\frac12\dfrac1{1+a+b} = \dfrac1{1-(a+b)^2},
\end{align}\right.$$

$$
\begin{cases}
(\alpha+b)(a^2-2ab+b^2-1) = 1\\[4pt]
(\alpha-b)(a^2+2ab+b^2-1) = 1
\end{cases}\Rightarrow
\begin{cases}
\alpha(-2ab)+b(a^2+b^2-1) = 0\\[4pt]
\alpha(a^2+b^2-1)+b(-2ab) = 1,
\end{cases}
$$$$
\begin{cases}
(\alpha^2-b^2)(-2ab) = -b\\
(\alpha^2-b^2)(a^2+b^2-1) = \alpha\\
\end{cases}
\begin{cases}
2a(\alpha^2-b^2) = 1\\
a^2+b^2-1 = 2\alpha a
\end{cases}
$$

$$2a(\alpha^2+a^2 - 2\alpha a -1) =1$$
with the same equation $(4).$

Comment: Let us say $p(u)=\frac{1}{2}\delta(u+1)+\frac{1}{2}\delta(u-1)$, would it be possible to have an analytic solution for $\alpha$? It seems that solving numerically still is the best way to go...

Comment: @Matt Thank you! The case is ready to check. If we have the complex $r,$ then the real solution via trig functions exists.